# Storyboard on Xcode 5 by default, what about use it just as an editor for view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, ios7

I never felt comfortable using storyboard, I always look at them as a sort of easy way to do easy things, but when customization come out they are sort of rigid or more verbous than code instead. That's my opinion, but I must tell the truth I never used them, so of course I might be wrong. The segue, unwind system it seems to me very inelegant solution and the fact that they return id object will require casts and a lot of if else coding to match correct identifier. 
It seems that there is no way to create a new custom initializer for view controllers, for me that's a big deal, beacause I use a lot in abstract classes.

Saying that, storyboard is the default options on Xcode 5, but not only, the storyboard editor is really "light years" away from nib editor. You can zoom, (usefull for auto layout), it seems an easier way if you want to create different paths between iphone and ipad interface, there are also more options, very important in iOS7. I'm talking about extendedEdges property and top/bottom layout guide.

Actual question: I'm wondering if it will be correct and possible to manage navigation in code "as usual" and use the storyboard as an editor and container of all application view controllers. Is there someone that uses this approach?

Comment: There is no need for casting with `id`. Just use `Type *object = [message returning id];` and if something is wrong you'll get runtime error.

Comment: There seems to be a clear question now. ColinE, esker, JoshC, glts, Carl Veazey, please revisit.

Comment: Well in my opinion the answer was pretty clear. I'm not liking stackoverflow lately, too many close, duplicate or downvote even if the OP do not deserve. The answer is yes, storyboard editor is really better than normal xib editor. Is possible to create a storyboard without using segue between VC, and we can create VCs just sending `- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` to the storyboard. I will develop a sort of storyboard manger that works as a factory giving the right VC using the class name.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of people out there that still don't use storyboards, and the fact that now by default when you create an app is done using storyboards doesn't mean you cannot use the previous approach.

Just create a simple app, with no view, and then create and add a new view controller with a xib.

Then, in your delegate, in the didFinishLaunch set the self.window.rootViewController to that view controller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController1;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I know and that's what I did, but what if you want to create a constraint visually using the topLayoutGuide positioning your elements in a xib?